# Singleordefault call only returning null when within a ternary operator

Tags: c#, linq, ternary-operator

I've found a fairly odd occurrence. When the following code is executed, mapFound evaluates to null despite 'mapLst' being populated and 'foo' also finding a matching map within the collection. Can anyone think of a reason for why that might be?

```
var mp = new MapObj() { 
                          keyObj = new KeyObj() { name = "Bob" },
                          valObj = new ValObj() { type = "Type1" },
                          category = "cat"
                      }
var foo = mapLst.SingleOrDefault(map => map.keyObj.name.Equals("Bob") &&
                                        map.valObj.type.Equals("Type1") &&
                                        map.category.Equals("cat"));
var mapFound = mapLst != null ? mapLst.SingleOrDefault(map =>
                                        map.keyObj.name.Equals("Bob") &&
                                        map.valObj.type.Equals("Type1") &&
                                        map.category.Equals("cat"))
                                : null;
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Exactly where do you set `mapLst`?

Comment: I'll update with more complete code, not sure if I'll be able to duplicate in a simpler system, but we'll see.

Comment: I created a console application with your code (adding the missing classes and adding `mp` to `mapLst` after creation) and I got the expected result (i.e. mapFound contained the correct value). There must be something different in the code you're running than the code you posted.